# Sample compression scheme and bounding the VC dimension

Tags: learning-theory

There is a compression function takes any sample $S$, for which there exists a function $h ∈ H$ with $L_S(h)$, and compresses it to a subset of $k$ sample points. Similarly, there is a decompression function $\rho$ which maps this compressed set back to a classifier $h'$ (not necessarily in $H$), such that $h'$ makes no mistakes on the original sample $S$.
Let $C(H)$ denote the smallest natural number $k$ such that $H$ admits a compression scheme of size $k$. $\mathrm{VC}$ stands for VC dimension.

I want to prove that $$\mathrm{VC}(H) ≤ C(H).$$

Comment: Nice question! What are your thoughts? Have you made any progress? Do you have any ideas at all?

Comment: What does "$L_S(h)$" mean? (From context, the sample $S$ is labelled, and the labels agree with $h$)

Comment: Consider the class $H$ of all functions from $\{x_1,x_2\}$ to $\{0,1\}$, which has VC dimension 2. Let us compress $\{(x_1,0),(x_2,0)\}$ to $\{(x_1,0)\}$; $\{(x_1,0),(x_2,1)\}$ to $\{(x_2,1)\}$; $\{(x_1,1),(x_2,1)\}$ to $\{(x_1,1)\}$; $\{(x_1,1),(x_2,0)\}$ to $\{(x_2,0)\}$. This shows that the "compression dimension" is only 1.

Comment: I am very new to this topic and have a lot of gaps in my understanding. So, trying to fill that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ shatters a set $S$ of size $\ell$, and has a compression scheme of size $k$. For each of the $2^\ell$ labelings of $S$, the compression scheme associates a labeled subset of size $k$, in an injective way. There are $2^k \binom{\ell}{k}$ such labeled subsets, and so $2^\ell \leq 2^k \binom{\ell}{k}$. Using $\binom{\ell}{k} \leq (e\ell/k)^k$, this shows that $2^{\ell-k} \leq (e\ell/k)^k$, and so $2^{\ell/k} \leq 2e\ell/k$, implying $\ell < 5k$.

Here is an example showing that we cannot improve this to $\ell \leq k$. Consider the set of all functions from $[k+1]$ to $\{0,1\}$. We give a compression scheme of size $k$. Given a labelling $(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_{k+1})$, we remove either $(1,\ell_1)$ or $(2,\ell_2)$ according to the parity of labels. This is injective, since we can reconstruct the missing label from the index of the missing point.

Comment: I just have a question. You mentioned we cannot improve it to l <=k. As l is basically the VC dimension. If we talk about axis aligned rectangles and we try to compress it, we'll get 4 points (highest, lowest, left-most, rightmost) and decompressing function would be that smaller rectangular hypothesis we just made. So, in this case, the VC dimension is also 4. Also, the k is 4. So, l=k. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Also, how did you come up with $2^k$ l choose k expression ?

Comment: For axis-aligned rectangles you actually need only two points. What you are missing is that $\ell$ is not a function of $k$. I showed that $\ell <5k$ always, but that it is not the case that $\ell \leq k$ always.

Comment: The expression $2^k \binom{\ell}{k}$ is the number of labeled subsets of $S$ of size $k$.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time. How exactly can you decompress from just two points of rectangle ? I would love to get your opinion on another question of mine that you edited on compression bounds.

Comment: Take two opposite points of the rectangle.

Comment: Then wouldn't you need the top and the bottom points of the rectangle to include all the possible points in the sample given the fact that it is realizable.

Comment: You can determine the other two corners from these corners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115815/discussion-between-brianoconner-and-yuval-filmus).